# which is not a part of executable file?

Tags: unix

Is it text segment, data segment, bss or stack.
I know that it contains executable instructions in encoded form.
But can encoded code be treated as text segment?

Answer (score 0):

The text segment is actually the segment that contains the bulk of compiled code; all the others typically contain data of some kind.

Of those mentioned, the only thing that is not a part of the executable is the stack, which is set up from scratch by the loader, all the others are loaded from the executable.